# deleting file from sdcard in android application for voice changer

Tags: java, android, audio-streaming, audio-recording

Hi i am making a voice changer application in which i have to delete some added pcm file in sdcard. The format in which the song is saved is:
    name.pcm

```
File f = new File(filepath + "/" + dir.getName() , SelectedFileOfListView + ".pcm");
f.delete();
```

where the  SelectedFileOfListView is the name of the selected file.And the following list the files in directory.

```
dir = new File(filepath,"Recordings");
        if(!dir.exists()){
            dir.mkdirs();
        }
        File tempFile = new File(filepath,"hi");
        if(tempFile.exists())
            tempFile.delete();
        file = new File(filepath + "/" + dir.getName() , "test.pcm");

        // check list of files in the directory
        files = dir.list();

        if (files == null) {
            list.add("No Recordings saved yet.");
        } else {
            list.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; ++i) {
                list.add(files[i]);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So heres a code for selected file deletion

```
            File f = new File(PATH_TO_DIRECTORY + "/" + SELECTED_FILE);
        if (f!=null && f.exists()){
//delete it
f.delete();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to delete a file named something with an extension .PCM

you should use the list function with the filenamefilter interface

like this

```
public static String[] getListOfFiles(String directory) {
    String path = directory;
    File f = new File(path);

    String[] list_names;
    // ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new
    // ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice,android.R.id.text1,list_names);
    list_names = f.list(new FilenameFilter() {

        public boolean accept(File fileDescriptor, String filename) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (filename.endsWith(".pcm"))
                return true;

            return false;
        }
    });

    return list_names;
}
```

if the list_names!=null that means there exists that file and so you delete it

else
do nothing or just show up a toast

hope it helps you.

Comment: thanks, but how can i delete a specific file? like for example honey.pcm programitically

Comment: i upvote but kindly helppppppppppppppppppp

Comment: see if want to delete a selected file you get the name of it...check if it exists or not delete it as simple as that.wait il post a code for you

Comment: thanks bro, i am waiting for your reply

Comment: check below i have again posted an answer.